# css3 white borders on rotated clipped divs

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, css-transitions, css-transforms

I modified this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/andsens/Yns9P/) to match my needs into this: [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p2hzmgok/)

The problem is the white border showing up, seems to be the -webkit-backface-visibility. Adding or removing it, makes a little difference, but not much. I only need to support Chrome, so a webkit only solution is not bad :)

```
.radial-progress .circle .mask,
.radial-progress .circle .fill {
   -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
   transition: -webkit-transform 1s;
   transition: -ms-transform 1s;
   transition: transform 1s;
   border-radius: 50%;
}
```

Any ideas for a fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like a subpixel rendering issue to me, which causes the white background-color to leak outside the child-div, even though this child-div should theoretically have the same position and size.

I don't have a real solution for this, but a workaround using "box-shadow" might be sufficient for your use case. Basically it just adds a small inset shadow, which covers the area which would otherwise bleed through:

```
.radial-progress {
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 0 #646464 inset, 0 0 1px 0 #646464 inset, 0 0 1px 0 #646464 inset, 0 0 1px 0 #646464 inset, 0 0 1px 0 #646464 inset;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/MattDiMu/hk0knaod/2/

Comment: Thank you for your approach @MattDiuMu ! I tweaked it to have a simpler syntax and better effect = "box-shadow: 0 0 0 1px ${color}"